# Can't SELECT * (ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got ADT)

Tags: php, sql, oracle, select, geospatial

**Update Update:**
I can query by defining the column name... so the issue is with the ***query*** `SELECT *` but I have close to *100* columns in my table.. I do not want to hardcore them all in and maintain that list.. why can't I use `SELECT *` ??

---

I am simply trying to create a button; the front-end where they user can choose one of three tables to export as .csv file. On click of a choice -> the choice is passed back to my PHP via `table:which;` then specific table will be queried in the oracle database and downloaded in the browser. Below is my attempt returning an error.

---

jQuery front-end call (export button click):

```
$('#export' + '.' + crnt).click(function(){
      let which = crnt;
      window.location.href = "export?table="+which;
});
```

---

PHP via slim route:

```
<?php
    
$app->post('/export', function ($request, $response, $args) {    

    $which = $_POST['table'];
    
    $config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/../../xx/xx.ini');
    $dbuser = $config['dbuser'];
    $dbpass = $config['dbpass'];
    $dbhost = $config['dbhost'];
    $dbname = $config['dbname'];
    $constr = $dbhost.'/'.$dbname;
    $conn = oci_pconnect($dbuser, $dbpass, $constr, 'XXX');

    if ($which == 'table_1'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_1';
        $columnsql = 'SELECT column_name FROM app.table_1';
    } else if ($which == 'table_2'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_2';
        $columnsql = 'SELECT column_name FROM app.table_2';
    } else if ($which == 'table_3'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_3';
        $columnsql = 'SELECT column_name FROM app.table_3';
    }

    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 
    $columnstmt = oci_parse($conn, $columnsql); 
    oci_execute($stmt);
    oci_execute($columnstmt);

    $columnnames = oci_fetch_array($columnstmt, OCI_ASSOC);
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    fputcsv($output, $columnnames);

    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
    }

    fclose($output);

    header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$which.csv");
    
    if (!@oci_execute($stmt)) {
       $error = oci_error($stmt);
       throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }

    if (!@oci_execute($columnstmt)) {
       $error = oci_error($columnstmt);
       throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }

});
```

---

**Error 500:** The above returns the below error in my dev tools network console -> preview response tab:

[image]

[image]

---

**Update:**

I have now updated all the `post` instances to -> `get` which fixed *post method not allowed* message but am still receiving the `ORA inconsistent datatypes error` ... is this something to do with my `headers` in the php? where I've included them? Do I need to specify a datatype in my `ajax` call as well? How do I handle the potential `*ADT*` datatype?

Comment: When you navigate to a url in your browser you'll be using making a GET request. You either need to change the method your route allows in slim e.g. $app->get, or use something like Postman to create a POST request.

Comment: Thanks so switching to get seemed to solve the errors above; but it seems my variable is not passing from ajax -> to the php for the table selection...

Comment: Yeah, that's because it's a POST variable, but you've now changed your request to a GET request. For testing, you could change $which = $_POST['table']; to $_GET['table'] or even $_REQUEST['table']

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense - I have made the update however am still getting the inconsistent data type error :/ - strange

Comment: Could you put the definition of tables with column datatypes ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 thanks - not sure what you mean?

Comment: What I mean is I saw some examples of the problem and it could be issue if the tables have object type as columns in it. e.g. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74647

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 well crap.. the response in that link is to buy some oracle php book?

Comment: Re: "the definition of tables with column datatypes".  What he means is update your question to show the formatting DDL that defines the table. Or the output of the sqlplus command 'describe <name of your table goes here>. as documented at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve019.htm#SQPUG040

Comment: You should have understood by now that the PHP Oracle extension is not able to handle geometry types. Starting a bounty won't change that.

Comment: @Olivier thanks for your candor; is there an alternative? 'not possible' seems a bit harsh for geometry types

Comment: If you want to export the geometry column in the CSV, you need to use an SQL function to convert it to text. If you don't want to export it, then you should give the list of the columns that you want to export. In both cases you will need to drop the `*` and give columns explicitly.

Comment: You need to provide detailed sql trace from oracle. You can execute `ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS 'sql_trace bind=true'` before your select and post that trace here. If you have no access to the database server, you can ask your DBA about this

Comment: The book in "the response in that link is to buy some oracle php book?" is actually a free PDF.

Comment: Try change while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))

Comment: @Ashok that was the first thing I tried....

Answer (score 0):

It is a weird request for extract column. It is not some thing like?

```
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'table_1';
```

You use OCI_ASSOC. And you can save a request with a function like

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) {
        write_head_column($output, $row);
        fputcsv($output, $row);
}

function write_head_column(&$output, $row){
  static $is_done;
  if(empty($is_done)){
    $head = key($row);
    fputcsv($output, $head);
    $is_done = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one+ of you colums is object, like `SDO_GEOMETRY` and this kind of column cannot be selected via `*`
You should use something like

```
SELECT c.shape.Get_Dims()
FROM cola_markets c WHERE c.name = 'cola_b';
```

@see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_geometry-methods.htm#SPATL498

Answer (score -2):

You can dynamically create the query by getting the column names and converting them all to text strings in the created query (even text can be converted to text).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/tostring-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

Are you going to put column names in the first CSV row?

Comment: 'Are you going to put column names in the first CSV row?' yes.